# Multi Collection GraphLookup and Join

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have  three collections within an IAM database.

`iam.policies`
`iam.resourceHierarchy`
`iam.roles`

The document structure within these collections is modeled as follows:

`iam.policies` - contains documents that define what permissions or collection of permissions (roles) one or more members has for a given resource. Each document is structured like this:

```
{
  'resourceID': string
  'bindings': [
    {'members': [string], 'permissions': [string]},
    {'members': [string], 'role': ObjectId('<uuid>')}
  ]
}
```

for example

```
{
  'resourceID': 'program1',
  'bindings': [
    {'members': ['user/user1@example.com'], permissions: ['projects.view']},
    {'members': ['user/user2@example.com'], role: ObjectId('role1')}
  ]
}
```

The `role` field within a binding references a role defined in the `iam.roles` collection.

`iam.resourceHierarchy` - contains documents that define what the ancestral relationship(s) are for a given resource. Each document is structured like this:

```
{
  'resourceID': string
  'parentID': string
}
```

for example

```
[
  {
    'resourceID': 'program1'
  },
  {
    'resourceID': 'project1',
    'parentID': 'program1'
  }
]
```

`iam.roles` - contains documents defining the roles that exist within the system. A role is simply a named abstraction ontop of a list of permissions. Each document within this collection represents a single role. For example

```
{
   'title': string
   'includedPermissions': [string]
}
```

for example

```
{
  'title': 'Program Manager',
  'includedPermissions': ['programs.view', 'programs.edit', 'projects.view', 'projects.edit']
}
```

---

What I am trying to do is recursively lookup the ancestral chain for a given `resourceID` and for each of the ancestors (including the `resourceID` itself) get the policy (e.g. the array of bindings from the `iam.policies` documents) and merge them all together.

I have used the [`$graphLookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#pipe._S_graphLookup) function to get the ancestral chain

```
db.resourceHierarchy.aggregate( [
   {
      $graphLookup: {
         from: "resourceHierarchy",
         startWith: "$resourceID",
         connectFromField: "parentID",
         connectToField: "resourceID",
         as: "ancestors"
      }
   }
] )
```

And that successfully returns the ancestral chain. Using the examples above I get the following output for project 1.

```
{
  'resourceID': 'project1',
  'parentID': 'program1',
  'ancestors': [
    {'resourceID': 'program1'},
    {'resourceID': 'project1', 'parentID': 'program1'}
  ]
}
```

But I'm having trouble with what to do next. What's the best way, as part of an aggregation, to now lookup the `bindings` for each of the ancestors from the `iam.policies` collection?

I've looked into the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) function, but I was not able to get it to join properly on the `bindings` field of the policies collection.

```
{
  'from': 'policies',
  'startWith': '$resourceID',
  'connectFromField': 'ancestors.resourceID',
  'connectToField': 'bindings',
  'as': 'bindings'
}
```

outputs (for project 1 for example)

```
{
  'resourceID': 'project1',
  'parentID': 'program1',
  'ancestors': [
    {'resourceID': 'program1'},
    {'resourceID': 'project1', 'parentID': 'program1'}
  ],
  'bindings': []
}
```

Does anyone have any recommendations or good examples of this?

Comment: If you are asking how to combine graphlookup with $lookup, add the results of graphlookup to the question and show how you use $lookup with  a simple input.

Comment: I added some examples for input and output.

Comment: Did you find a solution?